# How Do You Run Webpack from a JavaScript file?

Tags: node.js, webpack

As we all know, you can run Webpack from the command line using the CLI by running,

`webpack`

Which reads the file `webpack.config.js` and compiles your files accordingly.

Is it possible to do this same thing from within a file? In other words, is it possible to run Webpack *without* using the CLI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

https://webpack.js.org/api/node/

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

webpack({
  // Configuration Object
}, (err, stats) => {
  if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
    // Handle errors here
  }
  // Done processing
});
```

Comment: Can I do this within javascript that isn't running on nodejs? i.e. run webpack on front-end javascript webapp

Comment: how to import a configuration file?